# Create views for documents in Couchbase using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have Couchbase where documents are stored in json format
like 
QueueMessage/abc123
QueueMessage/pqr456

and content in this for QueueMessage/abc123

```
  {
    "queue_list": {
     "type": "cards.create",
     "id": "abc123",
      "userId": "abcd",
      "deviceId": "abcd-1dg",
      "status": "Accepted"
     },
      "id": "abc123"
    }
```

and for QueueMessage/pqr456

```
{
"queue_list": {
 "type": "cards.create",
 "id": "pqr456",
  "userId": "pqr",
  "deviceId": "abcd-78n",
  "status": "Accepted"
 },
  "id": "pqr456"
}
```

I want to create couchbase views using  userid and device id. how can i do this in ruby?

Comment: Create a model called QueueList.  In an action method, use rails json methods to parse your json String into a Hash.  Create a model instance feeding it  `your_hash['queue_list']`  as the argument.  You will end up with a model instance in your action method. Then use `form_for()` to create the form in your view.

Comment: Sorry my question was for couchbase views

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'couchbase' 

#Connect to qlists bucket:
client = Couchbase.new( 
    node_list: ['127.0.0.1:8091'],
    bucket: 'qlists', 
    username: '7stud', 
    password: 'abc123'
)

#Enter some data in the qlists bucket:
client['QueueMessage/abc123'] = {

  "queue_list": {
      "type": "cards.create",
      "id": "abc123",
      "userId": "abcd",
      "deviceId": "abcd-1dg",
      "status": "Accepted"
  },

  "id": "abc123"
}

client['QueueMessage/pqr456'] = {

  "queue_list": {
      "type": "cards.create",
      "id": "pqr456",
      "userId": "pqr",
      "deviceId": "abcd-78n",
      "status": "Accepted"
  },

  "id": "pqr456"
}

#Create a view:
view_doc = %q[
{
  "_id": "_design/qlists",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "userId_deviceId": {
      "map": "function(doc){ emit(doc.queue_list.userId, doc.queue_list.deviceId); }"
    }
  }
}
]

client.save_design_doc(view_doc)


#Use the view to retrieve data:
qlists = client.design_docs['qlists']

qlists.userId_deviceId.each do |row|
  puts "#{row.key}, #{row.value}"
end

--output:--
abcd, abcd-1dg
pqr, abcd-78n
```

I could not get `reduce` to work in a view.

Comment: I am facing this error   `NoMethodError (undefined method save_design_doc' for #<Couchbase::Bucket:0x35429e28>):`      as I am defining client as                                                                                
 `cluster = Couchbase::Cluster.new([ENV['COUCHBASE_HOST']])
                                                                                                        @bucket = cluster.open_bucket(Rails.application.secrets.couchbase_bucket_name)`

Comment: how do I write for `client['QueueMessage/abc123'] `    as it gives me undefined [] error for <Couchbase::Bucket:0x35429e28>

Comment: @mag, What gem are you using for couchbase?

Comment: I am using `gem 'couchbase', '2.0.0.pre.1'`